# Make a new tab appear on the left side of the current tab

Tags: html

When a link that creates a tab is clicked it usually opens a tab to the right side of the current one, but, as I have seen in some websites its possible to get it to open on the left side instead.

How do I get it to open on the left side?

Comment: @DarshakGajjar I'm just curious about how to implement it. I'm not coding anything.